# Angular preview docx using ngx-doc-viewer - 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: ngx-doc-viewer

I'm using ngx-doc-viewer to preview a docx document. My tag is

<ngx-doc-viewer [url]="url" viewer="google" disableContent="popout-hide" style="width: 100%; height: 75vh;" (loaded)="contentLoaded()">
.....

When I open the form I have this error ( from Browser log )

"GET https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2internal/about?fields=importFormats,kind&key=AIzaSyDV..............-... 401 (Unauthorized)"

What can I do? Do I need to register the app in google cloud to have the authorization?
Thanks in advance.
Sergio